# Checking script command-line arguments from inside a function

Tags: bash

I have the following very simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

checkCmdLineArgs() {
    echo -e "num input args $#"
    if (( $# == 0 )); then
        echo "$0 usage: install_dir home_dir"
        exit 255
    fi
}

checkCmdLineArgs
```

It does not work. If I run it like so:

```
./test.sh foo bar
```

It outputs:

```
num input args 0
./test.sh usage: install_dir home_dir
```

Any idea why it's failing?

Comment: BTW, don't use `echo -e` -- default builds of bash break the POSIX spec for `echo` by having it do anything other than print `-e` on output, but a compliant implementation can be enabled at compile-time or runtime; and other, more-compliant shells will behave contrary to your expectations. (This is unlike most bashisms, which *extend* the spec rather than *breaking* it, but `echo` is explicitly disallowed from accepting any options other than `-n`).

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly including the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside a function, `$#`, `$@`, and `$1` and onward refer to the function's argument list, not the script's. (`$0` is an exception, and will still refer to the name passed in the first argv position for the script itself; note that while this is *generally* the script's name, this isn't firmly guaranteed to be true).

Pass your script's arguments through to the function:

```
checkCmdLineArgs "$@"
```

Comment: Also, there is no `$0`. It starts at "$1" no?

Comment: @pedromss, `$0` is the name used for the script itself. Well, sorta/sometimes -- the caller can provide any name in that argv position they want, but that's what it is *by convention*.

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thanks for that. Will mark this as the answer when the timeout has lapsed.